# DataObject + TranslatableDataObject + ModelAdmin

Tags: internationalization, silverstripe, data-objects, modeladmin

Setup: SS 3.1.13, Translatable 2.0.8 and TranslatableDataObject dev-master.

I have two DataObject classes: "Facility" ($has_one) and "FacilityType" ($has_many) which I chose to be managed in ModelAdmin (as they are global properties of the site owner). I cannot however get TranslatableDataObject extension to actually enable translation for them, despite reading carefully the setup instructions [here](https://github.com/bummzack/translatable-dataobject).

Here's my _config.php:

```
// Set the site locale
i18n::set_locale('en_US');

SiteConfig::add_extension('Translatable');

// Set allowed locales
Translatable::set_allowed_locales(array('en_US', 'pl_PL'));
TranslatableDataObject::set_locales(array('en_US', 'pl_PL'));
Facility::add_extension("Translatable");
Facility::add_extension("TranslatableDataObject"); // tried "TranslatableDataObject('Title')" as well
FacilityCategory::add_extension("Translatable");
FacilityCategory::add_extension("TranslatableDataObject");
```

Could anyone please confirm that this setup should or won't work for me?

#### FacilityCategory.php

```
class FacilityCategory extends DataObject {
    private static $db = array(
      'Title' => 'Varchar'
    );

    private static $has_many = array(
      'Facilities' => 'Facility.FacilityCategory'
    );

    public function getCMSFields(){
        $fields = FieldList::create(
            TextField::create('Title')
        );
        return $fields;
    }
}

class FacilityCategoryAdmin extends ModelAdmin {
    private static $menu_title = 'Facility Categories';
    private static $url_segment = 'facility-categories';
    private static $managed_models = array(
        'FacilityCategory'
    );
}
```

#### Facility.php

```
class Facility extends DataObject {
    private static $db = array(
        'Title' => 'Varchar',
    );

    private static $has_one = array(
        'Category' => 'FacilityCategory'
    );

    private static $summary_fields = array(
        'Title' => 'Name',
        'Category.Title' => 'Type'
    );

    public function getCMSFields(){
        $fields = FieldList::create(
            TextField::create('Title'),
            DropdownField::create('CategoryID', 'Category')
                ->setSource(FacilityCategory::get()->map()->toArray())
                ->setEmptyString('-- select a category --')
        );
        return $fields;
    }
}

class FacilityAdmin extends ModelAdmin {
    private static $menu_title = 'Facilities';
    private static $url_segment = 'facilities';
    private static $managed_models = array(
        'Facility'
    );
}
```

Comment: You should either add Translatable OR TranslatableDataObject to each DataObject.

Comment: Thanks @wmk, but commenting out the Translatable invocations to the DataObjects did not help. Was it just a side note or you think it should definitely get it work?

Comment: Well, it was just a side note. For getting it working you need to share more code with us, e.g. your ModelAdmin, the getCMSFields method of the DataObjects etc...

Comment: @wmk Sure. I updated the question with the code you asked (only renamed `FacilityType` to `FacilityCategory`).

Answer (score 2):

I've looked into this for you.

I've installed a new SS site using:

```
composer create-project silverstripe/installer
```

I've then added translatable:

```
composer require silverstripe/translatable ~2.0.8
```

My _config.php looks like this:

```
<?php

global $project;
$project = 'mysite';

global $database;
$database = '';

require_once('conf/ConfigureFromEnv.php');

// Set the site locale
i18n::set_locale('en_GB');
Translatable::set_default_locale('en_GB');
MyObj::add_extension('Translatable');
```

I've created a ModelAdmin.

I navigate to /dev/build?flush=all in my browser

I then navigated to the ModelAdmin in the CMS and I see this:

[image: Translatable tab showing]

and

[image: Translatable tab contents]

I think part of the problem is you're using two translatable modules at once, you only need one.

Other than that, I don't know why you wouldn't see the translatable tab. Are you getting any PHP errors, have you ?flushed or done a /dev/build?

Comment: I checked that out on a fresh setup and it did not work with bot of my classes. The translation appears as long as there is no relation involved between the objects (just left the `$db` properties in both classes, devbuild/flushed and the Translation tab appeared). However, it still did not fully work in that the Create button went dead - it did not create translation on click.